# How to set background size (height & width)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, size, width

I'm very new to JavaScript.

My code so far:

```
$("#Stage").css(
  "background-image",
  "url(BG.jpg)",
  "background-attachment", 
  "fixed"
);
```

What I want to do is have the background image at a set size so lets say: `width: 100%` and `height: 100%`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You want to use `background-size: 100%`. Ensure that its browser support is compatible with your supported platforms.

```
$("#Stage").css({ 
     "background-image": "url(BG.jpg)", 
     "background-attachment": "fixed",
     "background-size": "100%"
});
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked but for some reason  "background-size": "100% 100%" doesn't work probably something to do with the program I am using - Edge Animate... any idea's of how to get both and height and width at 100% and stretch the image to the height and width..?

Comment: I might be a little late, but for those who see this comment: background-size: 100% 100%; stretches the image to 100% height and width of the container, not the image. So if you want the image to keep it's initial dimensions you need to have set an "auto" for either width or height e.g. background-size: 100% auto; (stretch image to 100% width of the container and set height automatically by the ratio of the initial image dimensions).

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me (inside a slider):

```
<!-- CSS -->
<style>
    div.img { 
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center center;
        -webkit-background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size: cover;
        -o-background-size: cover;
        background-size: cover;
    }
    div.img:nth-of-type(1) {background-image: url('img.jpg');}
    div.img:nth-of-type(2) {background-image: url('img.jpg'); 
    }
</style>

<!-- HTML -->
<div class="img"></div>
```

Answer (score -3):

This is just simple CSS, not jQuery. You can read more about `background-size` here: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp